# Find all webpages with bitcoin addresses posted on them (PHP)

Tags: php, search, web-scraping, bitcoin

I'd like to search the web for all webpages with bitcoin addresses posted on them.

Best way to do this? Sorry if this would be better for the Bitcoin SE.

Answer (score 0):

**An idea:**

First, you should have a database of sites that have the bitcoin addresses. Then, you can use python and screen scrap the data you need. And you can also do that with php using cURL.

Comment: Thanks @ignaces but the interesting part would be how to find all the sites with Bitcoin addresses in the first place.

Comment: @timpeterson well that's the difficult part. You have to actually act like Google to achieve that. Other idea: use a cronjob to scrape with the [DOMXpath function of PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is full, but it appears someone already did collected the list of bitcoin adresses, see:  http://directory.io/1

To find all (or at least some) pages that mention addresses you may try to search each adress in google and scrap the page adressess you need from the response.

Though, considering, the cosmic number of addresses the task may be computationaly infeasible.